# finding value of dynamically created combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I'm using VS2010,C#, I have a table that its data should be created dynamically (from an SQL server table), I have to add a combobox (with 3 items) to one of the columns, this combo box is also created dynamically, then I give each combo a unique ID, it has autopost back set to off and also enableviewstate and viewstatemode to true and enabled, when users changes values for some combo boxes (each row has a combox), and then presses the submit button, I want to have current state of my comboboxes but their selectedindex is 0 so I cannot use them, what should I do? what are my options? (I find each combobox using FindControl and unique ID of the combobox)

thanks

Comment: where are you using your combo box. on page or in gridview??

Comment: I'm creating combo boxes in my table, table rows are dynamically created and a combo box with 3 items is added in each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below answer for your above questions

1. First of all you need to register onchange event of combobox in Javascript while create dynamic combobox.
2. Put one hidden field on page
3. And then put the code in onchange event, set the value in hidden field using Clientid from onchange event and then get the value of hidden field from server side.

Comment: thanks rahul, would you please give me some sample codes about the implementation process?

Comment: Could you please follow the above steps and let me know if any error or   problem? It would be great you give me error message so i can diffenately solve your problem. I hope you understand. Currently i haven't same code . But  i have tried above code and it was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use postback.. here is a sample code snippet.. if you want to work on postback then then follow this.. else you can follow the approach as Rahul told you..

```
public partial class DynamicCombo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DropDownList list;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table table = CreateHtmlTable();
            list = new DropDownList();
            list.AutoPostBack = true;
            list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);
            list.ID = "cbo";
            list.Items.Add(new ListItem("value1", "1"));
            list.Items.Add(new ListItem("value2", "2"));
            list.Items.Add(new ListItem("value3", "3"));
            table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(list);

            pnl.Controls.Add(table);
        }

        private void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert(\"" + list.SelectedIndex + "\");</script>");
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private Table CreateHtmlTable()
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            table.Rows[0].Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[] { new TableCell(),
                                                       new TableCell(),
                                                       new TableCell()});
            return table;
        }
    }
```